# Firebase Database Keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This should be a simple answer for anyone with some basic database/firebase experience. I have looked throughout their documentation and cannot find an easy explanation of what I am looking for.

I am new to databases in general so if there is already a good post on here about my question, or somewhere else on the internet feel free to tell me.

**My Issue**

Lets just say I have an input field in my React app, and every time a user enters a value into it and presses enter, I would like for the data to get pushed to a certain part of my database, lets call that area, "tasks". I am actually able to do that, and can see the information created inside my tasks directory in real time every time I press enter. I can see that firebase enters it into the tasks directory with its own uniquely generated "key".

However, my problem is that I have another component where I would like to output all of the children from "tasks" to the screen. I think my issue is that I am not understanding the basic principles of how the data is stored and how to manipulate it(The official documentation from firebase was not much of a help).

**My attempt at the aforementioned**
In my component, I was attempting to use the javascript map function, that just iterates through the items in tasks, and outputs each one into its own div. The problem here is that the unique key identifier does not work with the array.map function. However, say I manually enter a list of tasks into the database, and give them my own key starting from 0, then ascending sequentially(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

The small picture below shows you what I mean. I manually entered those tasks, and can map through them, but if they have the randomly generated key from firebase, it does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to use .set() in order to specify your ID's. That said, the randomly generated ID's used by Firebase are used for an important purpose (timestamping), so overwrite those at your own discretion.

Try this if you're set on assigning the ID's manually:

```
var tasksRef = ref.child("tasks")
tasksRef.child('0').set({'hello world')}
```